# Como excluir vários itens do bd com checkbox marcado no ionic 3?

Tags: typescript, checkbox, ionic3

Gostaria de saber como excluir vários itens quando o checkbox for marcado, no  sqlite, com o ionic 3, na função excluir() eu não sei como excluir apenas os produtos que são marcados com checkbox. Eu pensei que dessa forma que estou tentando fazer, funcionaria, mas não excluiu nada. Se alguém puder me ajudar, obrigado.

code 
produto.html

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let produto of produtos">
      <ion-item>
        <input [(ngModel)]="modelo[produto.id]" value="{{produto.id}}" name="modelo" type="checkbox" ng-checked="produto.checked">{{produto.id}}
        <h1> {{ produto.barra }}</h1>
        <h3> {{ produto.deposito_nome }}</h3>
        <h3> {{ produto.quantidade }}</h3>
        <!--<h2 class="price">{{ produto.preco | currency:'BRL':true }}</h2> -->
      </ion-item>

    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button (click)="excluir()">Excluir Todos</button>
```

produto.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DatabaseProvider } from '../../providers/database/database';
import { SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InventarioProvider, Product } from '../../providers/inventario/inventario';
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';


@Component({

  selector: 'page-inventario',
  templateUrl: 'inventario.html',
})
export class InventarioPage {

    produtos: any[] = [];
      modelo: any[] = [];

    this.model = new Product();

        if (this.navParams.data.id) {
          this.inventarioProvider.get(this.navParams.data.id)
            .then((result: any) => {
              this.model = result;
            })
        }
      }
      ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.getAllProdutos();
      }

      getAllProdutos() {
        this.inventarioProvider.getAll()
          .then((result: any[]) => {
            this.produtos = result;
          });
      }

      excluir() {
         this.produtos.forEach(function (produto) {
  if (produto.checked) {
    this.modelo[produto.id] = produto.checked;
    return this.dbProvider.getDB()
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        let sql = 'delete from inventario where id = ?';
        let data = [produto.id];
        return db.executeSql(sql, data)
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: `let data = [produto.id]; ` 
Assim você não está atribuindo um array para data? 
Acredito que o correto seria 
`let data = produto.id`

Comment: Obrigada, acredito que possa ser isso mesmo

Comment: Caroline, vou postar como resposta ai você marca como concluída.

Answer (score 0):

Assim você está atribuindo um array para data

```
let data = [produto.id];
```

Acredito que o correto seria

```
let data = produto.id
```